# For se salta la primera iteracion

Tags: c++, bucle-for, bucles

estoy haciendo un proyecto de puntuaciones aun no esta terminado pero en la seccion cuando voy a ingresar datos a un arreglo "en el case 2" el for se salta la primera iteracion y comienza desde la segunda.

Elimine todo el codigo y solo deje la parte del for sin el case y asi si funciona correctamente pero cuando lo uno nuevamente al programa completo sigue con el mismo error. no se que pueda ser, si un error en el case o en las inicializaciones de las variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
//  int arr[10]; 
    int menu,i;
    string  Participantes[10];
    char nombres[20];
    int puntuaciones[10], c,num,cantidadP;
    int f,f2,temp,n;
    srand(time(NULL));


    do {
    cout<<"\t\tMenu 1"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"1.Hoja de Presentacion"<<endl;
    cout<<"2.Insercion de datos de los participantes"<<endl;
    cout<<"3.Puntuacion Mayor Heapsort"<<endl;
    cout<<"4.Puntuacion Mayor Burbuja "<<endl;
    cout<<"5.Salir del programa"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Elija la opcion que desea:"<<endl;
    cin>>menu;
    system("cls");

        switch(menu){
            case 1:{
                    cout<<"\t\t   TEMA:"<<endl;
                    cout<<"Puntuaciones mas Altas en Concurso Univeritario"<<endl;
                    cout<<"ALGORITMO HEAPSORT"<<endl;

                    system("pause");
                    system("cls");
                }
            break;
            case 2:{
                cout<<"Ingrese el numero de participantes del concurso"<<endl;
                cin>>cantidadP;
                for(i=0; i<cantidadP; i++){
                cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del Candidato "<<i+1<<": ";
                cin.getline(nombres,20);
                cout<<"\n";
                for(c = 1; c <=cantidadP; c++)
                {
                num = 1 + rand() % (101 - 1);
                puntuaciones[c]=num;
                }
                cout<<"Puntuacion del participante "<<i+1<<" agregada correctamente"<<endl;
                n = sizeof(puntuaciones)/sizeof(puntuaciones[0]);
                Participantes[i] = nombres;
                }
                cout<<"\n\n\t\tParcicipantes"<<endl;
                for(i=0; i<3; i++){
                cout<<Participantes[i]<<" Puntuacion:"<<puntuaciones[i]<<endl;
                }
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
}
            break;

            case 4:{
}
            break;

    }while(menu!=5); 
}
```

Comment: Revertí tu edición, pues no es correcto agregar la solución en el mismo cuerpo de la pregunta. Saludos